# Email form is refreshing page

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to make a quotation form which I have managed to complete but I am really struggling with the php side of things. I have borrowed some code online and tried to make it adapt with my form but it keeps refreshing the page, please if there is anyone out there that can help please?

Here is my code

```
    <?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "jhugill94@gmail.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "/Quotation.html";
$error_page = "/error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "/thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$senderFirst = $_REQUEST['senderFirst'] ;
$senderLast = $_REQUEST['senderLast'] ;
$senderNumber = $_REQUEST['senderNumber'] ;
$senderEmail = $_REQUEST['senderEmail'] ;
$issue_discription = $_REQUEST['issue_discription'] ;
$car_make = $_REQUEST['car_make'] ;
$car_model = $_REQUEST['car_model'] ;
$fuel_type = $_REQUEST['fuel_type'] ;
$engine_size = $_REQUEST['engine_size'] ;
$image_upload = $_REQUEST['image_upload'] ;
$msg = 
"First Name: " . $senderFirst . "\r\n" . 
"Sur Name: " . $senderLast . "\r\n" . 
"Contact Number: " . $senderNumber . "\r\n" . 
"Email: " . $senderEmail . "\r\n" . 
"Issue Discription: " . $issue_discription ;
"car_make: " . $car_make ;
"car_model: " . $car_model ;
"fuel_type: " . $fuel_type ;
"engine_size: " . $engine_size ;
"image_upload: " . $image_upload ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($first_name) || empty($email_address)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

/* 
If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
If you add a form field, you should add it here.
*/
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) || isInjected($first_name)  || isInjected($comments) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {

    mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results", $msg );

    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: There’s a lot of redirects here... where is it redirecting to? What is the url of this script?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, here is the link where I got the code from I have tweaked it but my knowledge on php is very minimal https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_form_to_email.cfm

Comment: also here is the link to the site html is going to get neater i usually just throw the code in and neaten it up after so i know where i am http://artoo.laurajames.x10host.com/Quotation.html

Answer (score 0):

### Debugging 101

Start at the beginning, and intentionally break it part way down; I.e., `die(‘good to here’);`. If you see “good to here” when you run the script, then remove it and work your way down the script.

That’s the most *naive* way to do it, but it can be effective.

Using the same idea, scan the script and keep track of variables so you manually follow the program flow. This way you can be more strategic about where you try break points.

One common problem is what we *think* the code is doing doesn’t match up to what it’s *actually* doing.

Since you know it’s redirecting in an unexpected place, look for where that happens (`header:` statements). These are all preceded by an `if` statement. What are the values being tested?

1. What is the value of `$_REQUEST['email_address']`?  I can’t answer that from the information given.
2. What is the value of `$first_name`?  Is it empty? Does it even exist?

And voila, you’ve found one of the problems.  `$first_name` is never assigned (you assigned `$sender_first`) and is actually generating a notice if you have error reporting set up correctly for your development environment. It’s also evaluating as empty, so the condition is true and it redirects to the error page.

Continue this same process to find the rest of the errors.